# Deterministic Function in SQL, PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone Explain DETERMINISTIC  function in Oracle?

- Benefits Of DETERMINISTIC function?
- Difference Between DETERMINISTIC function and normal Function?

Answer (score 2):

The `DETERMINISTIC` clause for functions is ideal for functions that do not have any non-deterministic components. This means that each time you provide the function with the same parameter values, the result is the same.

When you define a function you can simply add the `DETERMINISTIC` option to the declaration section, making sure that the function (or any functions or procedures it calls) does not depend on the state of session variables or schema objects as the results may vary across invocations.

This option instructs the optimizer that it may use a cached result whenever it encounters a previously calculated result.

See blow links for more information and examples:

[More information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm)

[Example 1](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2011/11/28/the-%20power-of-determinism-in-oracle-database-11g)

[Example 2](https://www.oraclerecipes.com/dynamic-sql/deterministic-functions-to-improve-performance)

Comment: Thanks Mahdi, But Practically ,  I am not able to understand how Normal function gives different output while parameter Value are same ? Can you give any Example on this ?

Comment: See this link for your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm

Comment: For example, a function might contain a database lookup from some table that was updated between function calls, or the result could depend on the current date or time.